# How to make a panel adjustable using jquery?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a two panel, one left and second right in my html page. Left panel is collapsible. I want that panel to adjustable too. How to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: What? Examples please. "Adjustable" could mean a thousand things.

Comment: Adjustable means, resize the panel by dragging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New plug-in of JQuery contains method $`("#resizable").resizable();`, We need to add **UIjquery.js** file along with **jquery.js**.

This [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) has example of re-sizable.